# Using external API client JS in Vuejs SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I just started using Vuejs and I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party's API clients JS library. The Vue application uses `vue-router`. The 3rd party API client is built on `axios`.

The API client JS looks like:

```
function RestClient() {}

RestClient.prototype.getUsers = getUsers;

async function getUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

To integrate this into Vue, I have included `axios` and `rest-client.js` script path in the `index.html` file:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rest-client.js"></script>
</head>
```

And in `main.js`

`Vue.prototype.$restClient = new RestClient();`

This made it accessible to all the components. And it works fine. As in, I'm able to access the RestClient functions from `vue components`.

Is this the right way to handle such a process? Can't help but wonder if  there might be a better way.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read about [Vue plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html).

> Plugins usually add global-level functionality to Vue.

Extending Vue prototype is actually encouraged by the docs:

```
// 4. add an instance method
Vue.prototype.$myMethod = function (methodOptions) {
  // something logic ...
}
```

For such a simple usecase it may be enough, but let's say that you'd also want to have a loading indicator component triggered on API call. It may make sense to bundle and distribute them together using a Vue plugin. You can then install all the stuff plugin consists of with a single statement.

This is exactly what [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/install.js) does.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer anything, prototypes for things like a repository pattern are suggested methods of sharing information in components, just because there's a 'plugin' doesn't mean it's some how cleaner.

Comment: Exactly that's why I added _might_ and _debatable for such a simple usecase_. I'll update the answer to be more clear.